# Prevent xfce4-notifyd in Xmonad from taking focus

Tags: xfce, xmonad

How to prevent notifyd notifications from taking focus in Xmonad and XFCE?

Answer (score 9):

From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1065196, add doIgnore for Xfce4-notifyd in your ManageHook.  See below in xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Xfce
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers

main = xmonad xfceConfig {
, manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageHook xfceConfig
}

myManageHook = composeAll
 [ 
  , className =? "Xfce4-notifyd" --> doIgnore
 ]
```

Comment: Is this possible in Ubuntu with Unity ?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but looks like people are finding success install XMonad on Ubuntu if that's what you're asking

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I meant how to prevent applications from taking focus. I have only found the opposite, telling compiz which applications to "remove" from the focus stealing defence mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use XMonad, but I had this exact issue after upgrading from XUbuntu 23.04 to 23.10, and I solved this by ensuring the following in Settings → Window Manager Tweaks:

[image: Screenshot from Window Manager Tweaks]

that is:

- “Activate focus stealing prevention” is enabled
- “Honor standard ICCCM focus hint” is enabled